# How to add a prefix discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const TOKEN = process.env.TOKEN;
const prefix = ".";

bot.login(TOKEN);

bot.on('ready', () => {
  console.info(`Logged in as ${bot.user.tag}!`);
});

bot.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'ping') {
    msg.channel.send('pong');

  } else if (msg.content.startsWith('!kick')) {
    if (msg.mentions.users.size) {
      const taggedUser = msg.mentions.users.first();
      msg.channel.send(`You wanted to kick: ${taggedUser.username}`);
    } else {
      msg.reply('Please tag a valid user!');
    }
  }
});
```

currently that is what im using im trying to make it so i have to type `.ping`to get the message `Pong` but i cant figure out how to get the prefix to use

Answer (score 0):

You could use this code to get the command name:

```js
bot.on('message', msg => {
  const command = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).split(' ')[0]
  if (command === 'ping') {
    msg.channel.send('pong');
  } else if (command === 'kick') {
    if (msg.mentions.users.size) {
      const taggedUser = msg.mentions.users.first();
      msg.channel.send(`You wanted to kick: ${taggedUser.username}`);
    } else {
      msg.reply('Please tag a valid user!');
    }
  }
});
```

Note that this changes the kick command from `!kick` to `.kick`.

I recommend reading [this section of the Discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/commands-with-user-input.html#basic-arguments) for how to setup commands (and also user arguments if you need).

Comment: Thanks! i will definitely look at that.

Comment: @Og_8fw You're welcome! If this or any answer solved your problem please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/362830) by clicking the check mark. This indicates that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. See also [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

You can check for a concatenation of the `prefix` and the command name.

To check for `.ping` where `prefix` is `.`

```js
if (msg.content === prefix + 'ping') {
  // do something
}
```

To make it safer you can make it return early by checking if the message starts with the prefix.

```js
if (!msg.content.startWith(prefix)) {
  return;
}
```

This way when that check passes, you can slice away the prefix, and check the command name directly without having to worry about the prefix.

```js
const commandName = msg.content.slice(prefix.length); // remove prefix character(s)

if (commandName === 'ping') {
  // do something
}
```

All together it'd look like:

```js
const prefix = '.'

bot.on('message', msg => {
  // not start with prefix -> return early
  if (!msg.content.startWith(prefix)) return;

  // remove prefix to get command name
  const commandName = msg.content.slice(prefix.length);

  // check for command name directly
  if (commandName === 'ping') {
    // do something
  } else if (commandName === 'kick') {
    // do another thing
  }
}
```